# Add a column to a Dataframe that will take the value True or False with a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I would like to add a column 'is_drama' to df that will take the value True or False depending on whether the content belongs to the Dramas category on Netflix in the colums listed_in

Can you tell me what the function would be and how I could add this new column to my dataframe? Thanks

```
def drama(words):
  if 'Drama' in words:
    return 'True'
  else:
    return'False'

for i in df.listed_in:
  print(drama(i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```
   title            listed_in
0     3%  TV Dramas, TV Shows
1   7:19               Horror
2  23:59       Dramas, Movies
```

Then you can use **[`.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains)** to search column `listed_in` if it contains the word `"Drama"`:

```
df["in_drama"] = df["listed_in"].str.contains("Drama")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   title            listed_in  in_drama
0     3%  TV Dramas, TV Shows      True
1   7:19               Horror     False
2  23:59       Dramas, Movies      True
```

---

EDIT: To use function (use `.apply`):

```
def fn(x):
    return "Drama" in x


df["in_drama"] = df["listed_in"].apply(fn)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   title            listed_in  in_drama
0     3%  TV Dramas, TV Shows      True
1   7:19               Horror     False
2  23:59       Dramas, Movies      True
```

Or `lambda`:

```
df["in_drama"] = df["listed_in"].apply(lambda x: "Drama" in x)
```

Comment: It works perfectly well ! Thank you but I need to use a function

Comment: Waouh thank you so much !! You are too strong

Comment: Avoid `apply` (hidden loop) as much as possible. If needing to use a function, pass the whole DataFrame column in a function and return boolean Series.